# Extract file to a local plist file

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, scripting, plist

Situation: on macOS, with a shell script, or a terminal command, I need to extract an e-mail from a plist, generated who have a deep and large structure

after multiple  and  I have the below:

TotoEmailAddress
bob@blabla.org

I need the e-mail under the 2 string.

There is only one TotoEmailAddress on the plist file

I tried with the below command but without success:

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c print "TotoEmailAddress" com.bob.toto.plist

I cannot share the full plist but let me know if I need to share more informations..

Comment: Is it a binary plist or an XML plist? If it is binary then I don't know how to read it, maybe with `defaults`? if it is XML then you need to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77040845/edit") your question and add the XML structure, or else nobody can help you

Comment: You probably want to use the macOS builtin command `defaults` to read from the plist file, assuming your domain is `com.bob.toto` and your key is `TotoEmailAddress`, you might do `defaults read com.bob.toto TotoEmailAddress` to get the email value. Syntax is `defaults read DOMAIN KEY`, see `man defaults`.